# Can't remap keys from g600 mouse

Tags: 16.04, mouse, keyboard-layout, udev, logitech

I've followed [the most useful guide](https://martins-prolog.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/logitech-g600-in-arch-linux.html) I've found on how to remap keys from a mouse that also pretends to be a keyboard faithfully, but the bit where I use udev to remap the keys isn't working, so the later steps mean I remap important keyboard keys with xbindkeys. My `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-g600mouse.hwdb` is:

```
evdev:input:b0003v046DpC24A*  
KEYBOARD_KEY_7004c=zenkakuhankaku  
KEYBOARD_KEY_7001f=katakanahiragana  
KEYBOARD_KEY_70020=katakana  
KEYBOARD_KEY_70021=hangeul  
KEYBOARD_KEY_70022=angle  
KEYBOARD_KEY_70023=archive  
KEYBOARD_KEY_70014=brl_dot1  
KEYBOARD_KEY_70024=brl_dot2  
KEYBOARD_KEY_70026=brl_dot3  
KEYBOARD_KEY_7001e=brl_dot4  
KEYBOARD_KEY_7001a=brl_dot5  
KEYBOARD_KEY_70008=brl_dot6
```

Any clues on what is wrong?

Comment: The link in your post is broken. I believe you meant to link to [this page](https://martins-prolog.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/logitech-g600-in-arch-linux.html).

Comment: Argh, must have clicked one too many times when selecting it all :(

Comment: Could you resume the steps you did yourself? that guide received many comments updating/correcting instructions.

Comment: I have long lost access to that mouse :( This question will never be answered.